# Android - is there a way to use a message handler for a service and still be able to call it's methods from a bound activity?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to rewrite an existing service called AdamService so that it may extend a service class called BaseSensorService. AdamService's onBind() currently returns a binder that has a function getService which exposes it's methods:

```java
private final IBinder local_binder = new LocalBinder();
public class LocalBinder extends Binder
{
    public AdamService getService()
    {
        return AdamService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) { return local_binder; }
```

However BaseSensorService's onBind returns the binder to a message handler for the class:

```java
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
{
    isServiceBound = true;
    return mMessageHandler.getBinder();
}
```

Is there a way that I can bind to the message handler from the super class and and still be able to call some of AdamService's methods? Is there a way to maybe combine the two binders?

Comment: What is `mMessageHandler`, and what type of binder is it returning? Are any `BaseSensorServices` being exported, or are they just used locally, within this same app?

Comment: Each implementation of BaseSensorService is stored in a different application, one for each sensor. The idea was to try to make one app that could control and collect data from all of the sensors. mMessageHandler is a Messenger to a SensorServiceMessageHandler, which extends Handler.

Comment: One solution I was thinking of was to write a getHandlerBinder() function in AdamService, then I could use a local_binder to in onBind() and in the service connection's onServiceConnected, I could store the reference to AdamService, then call service.getHandlerBinder() and use the binder from that for the messenger. However, will this work if AdamService was started up in one application and then another application tries to bind to it? Is there a way I can check to see if a binder is from the same process as the current application?

Comment: You're not going to be able to use a `LocalBinder`-style solution to bind across 2 apps. You're going to need to think about your use case some more. Might be best to just enhance the `SensorServiceMessageHandler` to get the functionality you need.